# How to refer to a named capturing group in the Python PyPi regex pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-regex

As the title reads, we can easily match nested parentheses in regex with e.g.

```
(\(((?:[^()]+|(?1))+))
```

which will match balanced parentheses.
How can we use a named subgroup instead, as e.g. in

```
(?P<key>\(((?:[^()]+|(?\g<key>))+))
```

I'm not looking for a parser solution or anything but really for the pattern above in `Python` (`regex` module) or `PCRE`.

Comment: Use `(?&key)`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PyPi `regex` documentation](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), the **named backreference syntax** is

```
(?&NAME)
```

See a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqugKDOvREEDwtMrLk3SKFLXsA@wyU6ttIvR0LC3io7T0IzV1q7RsFcDimlqasdoaqrrKKiDsEZikkayZoqmQqJGkoamuqaC5v//AA):

```
import regex
print ( regex.sub(r'(?P<key>\((?:[^()]++|(?&key))+\))', '', '(ab(c)d) a(b()') )
# =>  a(b()
```